# Maximum likelihood geometric distribution

Tags: calculus, statistics, maximum-likelihood

This one i'm stuck on because I am not sure where the relative frequencies fit in:

> > The following data show the number of occupants in passenger cars observed during one hour at a busy intersection in Los Angeles. Suppose it can be assumed that these data follow a geometric distribution $p_X(k;\theta)=(1-p)^{k-1}p$, $k=1, 2,3,...$ Estimate $p$ and compare the observed and expected frequencies for each value of X.

\begin{array}{|c|c|}
\hline
\text{Number of Occupants}& \text{Frequency} \\ \hline
 1& 678\\ \hline
 2& 227\\ \hline
 3& 56\\ \hline
 4& 28\\ \hline
 5& 8\\ \hline
6+& 14\\ \hline
& 1011\\ \hline
\end{array}

$$L(p) = \prod_\limits{i=1}^{n}(1-p)^{k_i-1}p \\
= (1-p)^{\sum_\limits{i=1}^{n}(k_i-1)}p \\
\ln(L(p)) = \sum_\limits{i=1}^{n}(k_i-1)\ln(1-p)+\ln(p)$$

However, I'm not totally sure I'm heading down the right path here ....
A gentle nudge would be appreciated.

> > OK, continuing on from where @AhmadBazzi got me to...
> >
> > \begin{equation}
> >  \frac{n - \sum k_i}{1-\hat{p}} + \frac{1}{\hat{p}} = 0
> > \end{equation}
> >
> > $$\frac{p-1}{p} = (n-\sum k_i) \\ 
> > \frac{p}{p} - \frac{1}{p} = n-\sum k_i \\
> > 1 - n + \sum k_i = \frac{1}{p} \\
> > p = \frac{1}{1 - n + \sum k_i}$$
> >
> > Is this correct?
> >     If it is, this is another part I'm not sure about.
> >     n = 1011 I believe
> >     and $\sum k_i = 1 + 2 + 3 + 4 + 5 + ^ + ..$
> >     This is what I'm not sure about. I'm not sure if I have my variables correctly allocated and how to related it to the frequency table....

Comment: @AhmadBazzi the points are there for you if you want them. You have already done most of the work. I just need some clarification on if I am getting confused with the variables and how it relates to the frequency table.

Comment: Anyone else then?

Comment: This is correct $\hat{p} = \frac{1}{1 - n + \sum k_i}$ is the MLE of $p$. This means given $k_1 \ldots k_n$, you can use the formula you have to compute your MLE.

Comment: @AhmadBazzi Thankyou very much Ahmad.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> **NOTE**: This answer was posted before OP edited the question and added the steps that I proposed.

Yes you're on the right track. You've got $\ln L(p)$ which is the log-likelihood function. Now, using simple calculus, you need to find $\hat{p}$ that maximizes $\ln L(p)$.

Just to organize your function, use
\begin{equation}
 \sum_{i=1}^n ( k_i - 1 )
 =
 \sum_{i=1}^n k_i - \sum_{i=1}^n 1 
 =
 \sum_{i=1}^n k_i - n
\end{equation}

\begin{equation}
 \ln L(p) = (\sum k_i - n) \ln(1-p) + \ln (p)
\end{equation}
The first order condition is
\begin{equation}
 \frac{\partial }{\partial p} \ln L(\hat{p}) = 0
\end{equation}
i.e.
\begin{equation}
 \frac{n - \sum k_i}{1-\hat{p}} + \frac{1}{\hat{p}} = 0
\end{equation}
Now find $\hat{p}$.

Comment: Hi @AhmedBazzi can you please check this? I still have some questions.

Comment: Oh yeah, so I continue by answering this question below? @AhmadBazzi ?